# Android Google weather data application source code giving error

Tags: android

I've downloaded as Android App source code from the following [link](http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_description-t337.html).

I'm getting the following error when I've imported the project into the workplace.

> [2011-06-30 21:52:49 -
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]
>   Unable to read C:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the
>   file specified) [2011-06-30 21:52:49 -
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]
>   Unable to read C:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the
>   file specified)

Please any one can help me on this?

Comment: How are you importing the package?

Comment: do you have an AndroidManifest.xml file?  Did you make sure that that location is your eclipse workspace location?

Comment: @Otra I don't have that !dea, I'm a beginner to Android.

@Mutmatt I think you're right, Let me check that. As per my knowledge its not there.
Please guide me how to get that file and include it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello @Otra I got it, you're right there were few packages missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions on how to import the project:

1. Download the zip file.
2. Export the zip file into your workspace.
3. Once you have the folder, open eclipse.
4. At the top: file -> new -> android project
5. Under **Contents** click **Create Project From Existing Source**
6. Under **Browse**, navigate and click on the folder called WeatherForecast (Do not go into the folder, just click it so it highlights).
7. Click Finish at the bottom.

that's it. you should have a project in eclipse called weather forecast.

Comment: Thanks... Let me try this tonight.

Answer (score 0):

And also you have to change the API level of your project. If its not working check whether the Android libraries are added in your build path.

Comment: Not really an answer in itself - should have been left as a comment